# Iptables rules for remote mysql server

Tags: centos, iptables, mysql

I have a local mysql database on a centos server which causes a lot of load because there are a lot of queries made towards it. I want it hosted on its own server but i dont want every single bruteforcer out there to be responded to (even negatively). 
Is there a way to allow access to the port 3306 only to 3 - 4 ips, from iptables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the following rules should work, regardless of all your other rules, replacing `$IPADDRESS` with each IP address you need to allow;

```
iptables -I INPUT 1 -p tcp --dport 3306 -s 0.0.0.0/0 -j DROP
iptables -I INPUT 1 -p tcp --dport 3306 -s $IPADDRESS -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT 1 -p tcp --dport 3306 -s $IPADDRESS -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT 1 -p tcp --dport 3306 -s $IPADDRESS -j ACCEPT
```